# Airflow Operator for Alteryx

Tags: airflow-scheduler, alteryx, airflow

Has anyone written or knows the whereabouts of an Airflow Operator for Alteryx?  Trying to automate the execution of an existing Alteryx workflow, typically executed manually.  If this helps at all, both Airflow and Alteryx are behind the same firewall in an on-prem datacenter.

**For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I recognize there are better ways of starting an Alteryx workflow other than Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently not an Airflow Operator for directly executing Alteryx workflows on Windows.  However, with the existing PythonOperator and Python libraries like `pypsrp` and `pywinrm`, one is able to remote into the Windows box that operates Alteryx and execute PowerShell commands to run Alteryx via the command line.

[PYPSRP - Python Library](https://pypi.org/project/pypsrp/)

[PYWINRM - Python  Library](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to execute an Alteryx workflow through pywinrm?